# Serializer class as property of Model class - is it bad practice?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, orm

I want to write a custom command that requires separate serializers for multiple Model classes. In order to make that iterable, I thought it might be a good idea to add a custom property to the Models involved.

Following is a short example of what I envisioned, inside an app:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    # field properties, etc.
    command_serializer_class = FooCommandSerializer


# serializers.py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class FooCommandSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo


# management/commands/foo_command.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class FooCommand(BaseCommand):
    for model_class in [Foo, OtherModels]:
        qs = Foo.objects.all()
        # do things
        serializer = model_class.command_serializer_class(qs, many=True)
        
        print(f"Model has {len(serializer.data)} records.")
```

At a first glance, it seems redundant to specify the Serializer to the Model, since it's a one-to-one association the other way around - as in, a Serializer must have one specific Model defined in the metaclass.

However, I've found no way to list Serializers using a specific Model, so this seems to cleanest solution for me.

Is it good practice, or can bite me in the long run? Is there any reason for me not to do it, or find another way to iterate through Models this way?

Comment: It is okay to add something like this. But, in reality - this may not work in all cases. For example - you may need to use nested serializer in case of `GET` request and may not need the same in `POST` request.

Comment: @JPG it's not intended to be used via HTTP endpoints. While I utilize django-rest for the project, here I just invoke Serializer classes because they seem practical for JSON conversion.